# touchpad does not click on tap

Tags: 16.04, mouse, touchpad, synaptics, tap-to-click

My mouse left click and right click work fine but cant tap to click. So
I tried:

```
synclient TapButton1=1 TapButton2=3 TapButton3=2
```

The error says:

```
Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?
```

I also tried to install synaptics-package-manager and was able to achieve the result like tap on click and scrolling but at the cost of my keyboard.
When I enable xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-hew16.04 it prompted to uninstall the following four packages as in the image:

[image: the package prompted to remove these 4]

Was able to achieve mouse tap on click but lost the ability to type
I have Ubuntu desktop 16.04 LTS installed on my Lenovo ip320E

Comment: I've written an answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/995819/touchpad-gestures-and-holding-keys-does-not-work/995948#995948).  Let me know if it helps or you have questions by adding a comment here using @WinEunuuchsToUnix in the comment.

Comment: Oh Sorry I didn't saw the comment earlier.Actually I solved that problem but dont know how

Comment: Thanks for the update. I removed your question from the list of examples in the link.

Comment: sorry for the delay :)